# TF2 object detection training doesnt start with no error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using TF2.4 and when I start training the model I get this in my terminal:

`2021-02-05 07:44:03.982579: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)`

I know this is not an error and it is benign and is saying MLIR was not being used, but my training deosnt start while stays at this without stopping. Therefore after couple of hours I just quit the program.

How can I proceed with training?

Comment: I am getting the same error while attempting the [TF2 Object Detection API Tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Could you please create a fresh environment and follow the steps as mentioned in the document again. If the issue still persists please let us know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: This happens only when there is an issue on `tf.record` file. So i have re-done the `tf.record` and I realized there was a missing `xml` while there was no error in creating `tf.record` file. I have corrected that file and re created `tf.record` and problem solved.